Transform a column with same value for rows as a unique row
I am working in R. I've got this data frame :



X
Positive answers
N/A




Proposal 1
10
6


Proposal 2
15
6



I would like to transpose the N/A column as a row in the proposal column, like so :



X
Positive answers




Proposal 1
10


Proposal 2
15


N/A
6



I have tried the gather() function, but I haven't been able to get the desired result.

Is "N/A" column always 6? What happens when 1st row has 6 and 2nd row has 7?

The initial DF is the result of a survey. For one question, several answers where possible. For each answer, there is a column with two values : Yes if the proposal was ticked and No if not, N/A if none of the proposals was ticked. I have tried to get a table with the first column indicating the proposal and the other columns counting how many Yes (2nd column), No (3rd column) or N/A (4th column) for said proposal. I deleted the "No" column and want to get N/A as a row (N/A is always the same number : when a person didn't respond at all to the question (no "Yes"), all proposals are N/A).

If you don't want to complicate
rbind(within(dat,rm("N/A")),c("N/A",dat["N/A"][1]))


Thank you ! I doesn't seem to work. I get an error message : Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : invalid list argument: all variables should have the same length.

@ACD Does your data frame have 3 columns as in your example? If not you have to add all the missing columns in the vector.

Yes, the initial DF has 3 columns... I must get something wrong...

This is not a pivot/gather problem.
select(data, -Na) |>
  bind_rows(
    select(data, Na) |>
      rename(Answers=Na) |>
      mutate(X="Na") |>
      distinct()
  )


data <- structure(list(X = c("Proposal 1", "Proposal 2"), Answers = c(10, 
15), Na = c(6, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L
))

library(dplyr)


Thank you very much ! This is close to what I'm looking for : it creates a new column "Answers" with NA for each row and a last row NA with 6. And it also creates a last empty column "X" with NA in the last row.
